# Is there any way to make Hive work with Unicode table and column names?

Tags: hadoop, unicode, hive, create-table

It looks like Hive does not support Unicode in table and column names. For example, I can not create table with Cyrillic column names in Hive (see exception below).
Is there any way to make Hive work with Cyrillic table and column names?

I use:

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101

Subversion git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r b07b2906c36defd389c8b5bd22bebc1bead8115b

Compiled by jenkins on 2014-01-09T05:18Z

Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
```

```
hive> CREATE TABLE test2(`Имя` STRING, `НомерТелефона` INT);                                                                
NoViableAltException(10@[])
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:27461)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:27229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:26935)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:25185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4264)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2016)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1298)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:938)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1000)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
    FAILED: ParseException line 1:31 cannot recognize input near ',' 'INT' ')' in column type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unicode string on data/comments, but cannot use for database/table/column name.

See here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/User+FAQ#UserFAQ-DoesHivesupportUnicode?

Answer (score 0):

Hive 0.13 supports quoted Unicode column names. See [HIVE-6013](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013) for details. Hadoop 2.2 contains Hive 0.11, so update to Hadoop 2.4 or later to get this feature.